# Maintaining session variable on restart of browser

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic

I've created a session variable on my web page using the a column in my database called `username` and i've set the session timeout on the server to 20000. Now when i close the browser and open again to view user restricted pages it bounces me back to enter my username and password again even though i've lengthening the session timeout. its there a way i can still maintain the session even though closing the re opening the browser again. i'm using asp classic

Comment: Have do you think about the security risks that it implies? If I close the browser, I will expect that this will end all my sessions and that none coming after me could use my credentials..

Comment: This is what cookies are for

Comment: i did some sample with cookies but when i closed the browser and come back again it tell me to relogin again

Comment: You need to make the cookie non-expiring.

Answer (score 1):

The timeout has to do with the server, and you never want to raise it that high as it keeps the contents of that in memory. High session timeouts can lead to problems since the server needs to get that memory back, and high timeouts tell it to try not to.

Session variables should go away when a user closes their browser as that is the end of their session. If you want a more persistent storage, you should store the user's credentials in a cookie. You can control the expiration of the cookie and tell it how many days to keep on the client.

Session variables use a cookie to identify the user, but you don't have control over that cookies expiration, which is why it goes away when the browser is closed and the browser's memory is cleared. A cookie with a definite expiration is stored in the browsers cached storage so it persists even if the browser is closed.